# Tips for cleaning old glue from a carbon tubular wheel

Tags: wheels, tubeless

I'm replacing the tubular tire on an all carbon wheel (no aluminum brake surface) and cleaning the old glue off takes a long time.  What are some tips, products or tools I can use to speed up this process?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use any solvents because you have carbon rims.

Hot air is the best solution. Use the heat from a blow drier to gently soften the adhesive to where it will ball up with rubbing from your fingers.

If you only have a heat gun, you can use it but be careful as you can literally strip the paint off your rims with it (or cause your rims to deform/delaminate) - so I'd only use the heat gun very lowest setting.

A stiff pencil eraser can also help bring up the adhesive.